# Updating a record in ElasticSearch using olivere/elastic in google go

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am inserting a record in elastic search using go as stated here: https://github.com/olivere/elastic 
Now , if i have to partially update it(suppose if just one entry like 'name'), then i want to use UPDATE API. I cannot find any any documentation where they describe how to use this API/function in oilvere/elastic. I wonder if someone has used this before and could help me in this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I finally got this thing working. Here is the code that i used to get it done.

```
update, err := client.Update().Index("test3").Type("user").Id("2").Doc(map[string]interface{}{"location": message}).Do()
fmt.Println("updated id: ", update.Id)
```

This is working fine for me.

I tried another approach to update it but it wasn't working. I am posting it here so one can view it and check. It was something like this.

```
update := client.Update().Index("test3").Type("user").Id("2").Script(elastic.NewScript("ctx._source.location = loc").Params(map[string]interface{}{"loc": message}).Lang("groovy"))
fmt.Println("updated id: ", update.Id)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What is type('"user") means?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [github.com/olivere/elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic) always check the unit tests. They not only serve as a safety net for changes but also illustrate how to use the library. E.g. [update_test.go](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v6/update_test.go) and [update_integration_test.go](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v6/update_integration_test.go) come with a list of examples how to use the syntax explained in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-update.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **scripts**, here is an example of conditional update:

`_, err := client.UpdateByQuery().
        Query(query).
        Index(index).
        Script(elastic.NewScript("ctx._source = tag").Params(map[string]interface{}{"tag": doc}).Lang("groovy")).
        Type(docType).IgnoreUnavailable(true).
        Do(ctx)`

**index** is your ES index name in which the document resides.
**query** has all the necessary conditions(eg: update the doc only if age>18). For more knowledge on queries, please refer [here](https://www.ribice.ba/golang-elastic/).
The output of query will be available in ctx.source, which here i am setting to the params i passed.
You can also do something like:
`"ctx.source.salary = sal"`
in that case sal will be one of the params you will pass dynamically. I hope, it helps.