# Updating a record by query in ElasticSearch using olivere/elastic in google go

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am using ***olivere/elastic*** library for elasticsearch in my go app . I have list of values for a particular field (say **fieldA**) of elasticsearch document. I want to update a particular field of all document by searching on field **fieldA** .

This : [Updating a record in ElasticSearch using olivere/elastic in google go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989555/updating-a-record-in-elasticsearch-using-olivere-elastic-in-google-go/37994525#37994525) 
explains the update part. But in my case in don't have Id of documents to be updated . So, either i can make search call to retrieve document ids and then update them , or is there another way am missing? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update a list of documents, you can use the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). The [unit tests](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v6/update_by_query_test.go) give you a hint about how the syntax looks like. However, if you have individual values for individual documents, I guess there's no other way than updating them one by one. The fastest way to achieve that is by using the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-bulk.html).